# How do I format MyDate into DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2014

I have a day `dd/mm/yyyy` and I want to format it into `dd mm yyyy` in T-SQL. Please help me.

Comment: What _version_ of SQL are you using, e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc. ?

Comment: You can use `DATE_FORMAT( dateField , '%d/%m/%Y'  ) `

Comment: Are you sure you need to convert your date to a string/varchar? It is best to keep the date in its original date-type as long as possible and only "format as string" to display it to the end user.

Comment: As a student, you should be learning that graphical representation of resultsets is a function of your GUI, not TSQL. YOU might prefer to see dates with a specific format - someone else might prefer a different format. The database engine cannot do that for your application.

Comment: What data type is the "day"? Is it an `NVarChar(max)` or perhaps a `Date`? Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 1):

The below query will result in the desired output.

```
Select CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), @mydate, 106)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT("2021-05-11", "%d %M %Y");
```

The above query is for MySQL and for SQL-server you can use CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 103) instead of date_format

Comment: Thats not an SQL Server function.

Comment: Please update your answer rather than adding a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Dates don't have formats in SQL Server.  They are stored using an internal format.

Although I strongly, strongly encourage you to store such values as a `date`, it would appear than you have a string.  Hence, you can use string operations:

```
select replace(day, '/', ' ')
```